# Why is visual studio not recognizing is_open() function

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void Readfile(string fname)
{
    ifstream infile(fname);
    if (is_open(infile))
    {
        while (!infile.eof())
        {
            string sline = "";
            getline(infile, sline);
        }
        infile.close();

    }
    else
        stderr << "unable to open file" << fname << endl;

}
```

Visual studio says identifier "is_open" is undefined even though I included the fstream library.

Comment: It is a member function.

Comment: Regarding one of your future problems, read [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`is_open`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/is_open) is a method of the `std::ifstream`. Use `infile` object to call it:

```
ifstream infile(fname);
if (infile.is_open())
{
   //....
}
```

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds!